# C# / WPF : Rendering HTML from a string onto a WPF control

Tags: c#, html, xml, wpf, excel

I'm writing a program to display the contents of an Excel worksheet using a Grid. To that end, I'm retrieving the worksheet as one big string full of XML using Office Interop, like so :

```
// Get the cells Range from Excel:
Range rng = sheet.get_Range(Cell(row1, col1), Cell(row2, col2));
// Get the XML representing that Range:
return rng.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet);
```

I could create a FlowDocument from this XML string, and if I do assign it to a control on my GUI then that control will render the XML so that it looks exactly like what Excel shows. But I will have all the cells in the Range rendered onto a single control, which is not what I want : I want to be able to render any given cell onto any given control.

I couldn't find a fast and elegant way to extract the XML for individual cells via Interop : it just takes forever and a week. So I spent a whole day writing a class that parses the big XML string into an array of XML fragments each representing a cell. The strings in that array look like this :

```
<Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><Font       html:Color="#000000">Some random text with </Font><B><Font        html:Color="#000000">some bold characters</Font></B><Font html:Color="#000000">, and so on and so forth</Font></ss:Data></Cell>
```

This is actually HTML : from Visual Studio's debugger I can use the HTML viewer and it'll show me this :

Some random text with **some bold characters**, and so on and so forth

And by the way, this line was rendered correctly by the Stack Overflow website as soon as I pasted it in.

So I felt pretty confident that I could now create, programmatically, FlowDocument objects for each Excel cell, assign them to my GUI controls, and I'd get nice rendering of my Excel cells in any layout I care to program.

Except this doesn't work. When I put the FlowDocument into a control, the control just displays the HTML source code, it does not render it.

Here's how I create the FlowDocument :

```
FlowDocument tmp = new FlowDocument();
TextRange tr = new TextRange(tmp.ContentStart, tmp.ContentEnd);
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string_full_of_html);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
tr.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

(to explain : I allocate a FlowDocument, then create a TextRange through which I'll load the HTML, then turn my string full of HTML into a stream, then feed that stream to the TextRange)

I've tried different "DataFormats" : HTML, oddly, doesn't work. It gives me the exception "'HTML Format' data format not supported". RTF works but, like HTML, only displays the string I fed in, it doesn't render it.

Visual Studio can render my XML strings with its "HTML Visualizer", and I understand it is written with WPF. So I know there's a mechanism in there that does what I need, but I can't find it. That's where you come in, brave code Jedis !